# Relation between Retieve AND Update in a Dynamic CRM PLUGIN

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a relation between Retrieve and Update in a Dynamic CRM Plugin?
For example if I am retrieving only one field:

```
Entity e = (Entity)service.Retrieve("EntityLogicalName", EntityGuid, 
new ColumnSet(new string[] {"entityid"}));
```

Can I update another field in the Entity e that has NOT been retrieved?
For example:

```
e.Attributes["AnotherEntityField1] = "test1";
e.Attributes["AnotherEntityField2] = "test2";
service.update(e);
```

By NOT including all fields that to be updated in the Retrieve, may this cause some hidden issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, as it appears, that you are just retrieving the entity's primary key, `entityid`, you won't need to do the retrieve.

```
Entity e = new Entity("EntityLogicalName") { Id = EntityGuid };
e.Attributes.Add("AnotherEntityField1", "test1");
e.Attributes.Add("AnotherEntityField2", "test2");
service.Update(e);
```

If you are doing a retrieve to confirm the record exists you need to try/catch or use a retrieve multiple since a `Retrieve` will throw an exception if the record does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is perfectly acceptable and won't cause any problems.  Since you obtained the Entity instance via a Retrieve operation the required LogicalName and Id will be set correctly for an update.

Your code would need to read as below for adding new attributes not retrieved initially otherwise you'll get a `KeyNotFoundException` as the `Entity` type is just a wrapper over `Dictionary<string,string>`.

```
e.Attributes.Add("AnotherEntityField2","test2");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to update an entity you don't need that an field exists in the attributes colletion, but to avoid the exception "The given key is not presented in the dictionary" is a good practise to check first if the Attributes Colletion contains the field you want to updated. If yes just update it otherwise you have to add it to the Attributes Colletion of the entity.

```
if(e.Attributes.Contains("AnotherEntityField1"))
{
e.Attributes["AnotherEntityField1"] = "test1";
}
else
{
e.Attributes.Add("AnotherEntityField1", "test1");
}
```

// now update operation